# Rudder add new directive shows no parameters

Tags: rudder

I've upgraded to rudder 4.2.1 and now I can't create new directives because I get `This Technique has no configurable parameters.` under Parameters.

I see that there has been a change recently that introduced this behavior (see [Redmine](https://www.rudder-project.org/redmine/issues/11642)). However somehow this always seem to return an empty list in my installation.

I can still edit existing directives.

Is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just found the problem and are in the process to release a 4.2.2 with a correction. It should be available tomorrow.

In the meantime, you can downgrade to 4.2.0 or build the Rudder war from commit:e71e5730a968ada9de2743255edfea6e3f286061 and replace the one in `/opt/rudder/share/webapps/rudder.war` and restart Rudder (make a copy of that one in case something goes wrong).

Note that you can still modify existing directive, clone existing directives and modify them, or create them with API - but we are very aware that it is not at all convenient workarounds.

Comment: Thanks, I've upgraded to 4.2.2 and can confirm it working again.

Comment: Perfect! Sorry for the inconvenience :(